# how to separate concerns in the below fn

Tags: clojure

The function below does 2 things -

- Checks if the atom is nil or fetch-agin is true, and then fetches the data.
- It processes the data by calling (add-date-strings).

What is a better pattern to separate out the above two concerns ?

```
(def retrieved-data (atom nil))

(defn fetch-it!
  [fetch-again?]
  (if (or fetch-again?
            (nil? @retrieved-data))
    (->> (exec-services)
         (map #(add-date-strings (:time %)))
         (reset! retrieved-data))
    @retrieved-data))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible refactoring would be:

```
(def retrieved-data (atom nil))

(defn fetch []
  (->> (exec-services)
       (map #(add-date-strings (:time %)))))

(defn fetch-it!
  ([]
     (fetch-it! false))
  ([force]
     (if (or force (nil? @retrieved-data))
       (reset! retrieved-data (fetch))
       @retrieved-data)))
```

By the way, the pattern to seperate out concerns is called "functions" :)

Answer (score 2):

To really separate the concerns I think it might be better to define a separate fetch and process function. So that in no way they are complected.

```
(def retrieved-data (atom nil))

(defn fetcher [] 
   (->> (exec-services)
        (map #(add-date-strings (:time %)))))

(defn fetch-again? [force]
 (fn [data] (or force (nil? data))))

(defn fetch-it! [fetch-fn data fetch-again?]
 (when (fetch-again? @data))
  (reset! data (fetch-fn))))

 ;;Usage
(fetch-it! fetcher retrieved-data (fetch-again? true))
```

Notice that I also gave the data atom as an argument.